# 2 questions about using Like buttons for voting (not for promotions)

Tags: facebook-like

My questions are about this (pasted from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/)...

**"What makes up the number shown on my Like button?**

*"The number shown is the sum of:*

*-The number of likes of this URL*

*-The number of shares of this URL (this includes copy/pasting a link back to Facebook)*

*-The number of likes and comments on stories on Facebook about this URL*

*-The number of inbox messages containing this URL as an attachment."*

With that in mind, let's say I create a feature to let users submit ideas to improve my site, and I want to let users vote on the ideas by clicking Like buttons next to each idea.

(For simplicity, let's also say it's okay if they click more than one Like button.)

When a user clicks a Like button, a story about it shows up in his/her friends' newsfeeds, which brings up my 2 questions:

1.) If one of those friends comments on it with "That idea sucks," will that comment still add to the Likes count?

I know the content of the comment doesn't matter, but that user is clearly expressing his *dislike* of the idea, not liking it.

2.) Can the same user generate 2 or more Likes?

From the above, it seems like he/she could click the Like button, and then send a FB message with the URL as an attachment, which would generate another Like.

Thanks for the clarity!

P.S. This other thread was useful, but there were no conclusive answers:

[Voting for items via facebook like?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/5240760/voting-for-items-via-facebook-like)